# Can I view comments of a deleted post?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-questions

Someone replied to my comment on a post that was deleted because it's a duplicate (my name is mentioned in the comment). Is there any way to read [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572657/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-email-t-string-expecting-in-on-li?noredirect=1#comment51101469_31572657)?

Comment: Nope, unless you are a mod.

Comment: @any_moderator can you copy and paste the comment here ? I'm dying to know it because I think it's gonna be very funny :D

Comment: or are 10k+ ;-) you have a bit to go. Edit: yeah only a mod can undelete.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you were the commenter, tell me the comment :D

Comment: Sure, no problemo. The comment was: *Shouted? lol when was this? I must say that, questions like these should be closed and downvoted and answers not submitted, because they tend to open up great big cans of worms. Being that, a full solution hasn't even been found amidst answers given so far, and risks at staying closed (which it should and should also be deleted if anything; it won't serve anyone here). It's just a very bad question and is considered as off-topic anyway. I for one, wouldn't have touched this with a 20-foot pole, even with a HAZMAT suit and rubber gloves ;-)*

Comment: as per your *"I remember when user Fred -ii- (I believe that was the name) shouted at me for answering such a question :D"* - as per the *very bad question* http://stackoverflow.com/q/31572657/ which died; as it deserves.

Comment: @Fred-ii- why are you so rough with newcomers :D?

Comment: which one(s)? *grin* - let's call it *"tough love"* ;-)

Comment: @abdoadel one thing about high rep users... since they have more visibility/experience, they tend to see/have seen more crap than other users. Yes that makes them jaded and cynical over time.  It sucks and sometime translate into harsh messages. But it's understandable to an extent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Look at the colors... Your name attribute is also missing a closing quote on the email. –  chris85 1 hour ago
>
> stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/… I hate running out of close votes... –  Marc B 1 hour ago
>
> @MarcB I remember when user **Fred -ii-** (I believe that was the name) shouted at me for answering such a question :D –  Abdo Adel 1 hour ago
>
> @AbdoAdel: it is very low hanging fruit. people need to learn how to read their code, and actually read error messages. –  Marc B 1 hour ago
>
> @MarcB Had one left :) –  Rizier123 1 hour ago
>
> `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is better. `if ($_POST['submit'])` does nothing. –  Fred -ii- 1 hour ago
>
> then you have another syntax error => ehco which everyone didn't catch ;-) –  Fred -ii- 1 hour ago
>
> oh and `if (!$_POST('email'])` ol RR caught that and chris85... @Rizier123 good catch. this thing's riddled with syntax errors. blech :p amongst other errors. *wowzers!* –  Fred -ii- 59 mins ago
>
> then there's the ticks in preg_match('`[A-Z]`'.$_POST['password'])) –  Fred -ii- 55 mins ago
>
> @AbdoAdel *Shouted?* lol when was this? I must say that, questions like these should be closed and downvoted and answers not submitted, because they tend to open up great big cans of worms. Being that, a full solution hasn't even been found amidst answers given so far, and risks at staying closed (which it should and should also be deleted if anything; it won't serve anyone here). It's just a very bad question and is considered as off-topic anyway. I for one, wouldn't have touched this with a 20-foot pole, even with a HAZMAT suit and rubber gloves ;-) –  Fred -ii- 44 mins ago

---

As per the original Stack post: (for those 10k+ members who can see it).

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/31572657/

Comment: [It's been answered here...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299944/view-comments-of-a-deleted-post#comment224310_299944) - lol

Comment: yes... it has been