# Can someone provide me a copy of the comments on a deleted post?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-questions, moderation

I ran through a review queue again. I was getting tired, so I started being a bit more frank with my comments on low quality questions.

I saw a reply to one of them in my feed, but within a minute it was a dead link, as the author retracted their question.

Searching for ways to view that comment, I only found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299944/view-comments-of-a-deleted-post) on Meta. Therefore, can I ask a moderator to please provide me a copy of the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007422/php-errors-redirect-to-localhost-folder-folder)?

This situation is bugging me, as I hope I wasn't rude. Also, I sometimes try to keep an eye on whether users ask a new question with improved quality - so positive feedback.

Comment: _"I apologize for @DanielBrose. He's correct, this question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow as your question is more 'product support' than it is 'development' related. Good luck in your search, flagging this to be closed as not appropriate for StackOverflow. –  [Sean](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5394941/sean) [49 mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007422/php-errors-redirect-to-localhost-folder-folder#comment53839376_33007422)"_

Comment: That was the comment in which you were mentioned. Apparently, Sean considered your suggestion to google the problem before asking to be a rude one.

Comment: I'd say that was pretty rude. No matter how off-topic a question is, that never gives you license to be offensive.

Comment: @TinyGiant, yeh - it was a case of me being fustrating at all the low qualities, as in human nature, the one i snapped at wasnt even the worst (though there was post lag so comment above wasnt there when i posted). I was at #18 in queue, and only one 'looks ok' - 87 reviews so far and i am so disillusioned as the times i take effort to reply and help people, they almost never edit & improve thier question, and so so so so many duplicates out there... Ill send him a chat apology, he wasnt the worst, but ive never used a bookmark as often as 'how-to-ask', seems i constantly copy+pasting it

Comment: And such is the moderation of a community. It takes a thick skin and an immutable belief that all users are capable of doing better. The saying stands "if you don't have anything nice to say, don't say anything at all". You don't *have* to leave a comment at all, you can just click recommend deletion / unsalvageable and move on. The fact is that you probably won't be able to help the majority of individuals, but you can help the community by helping remove the garbage and focus on the good. I hope your outlook improves :)

Comment: @TomHutchison - cant chat with you (your not 20 rep yet), but will post here and in link in another question of yours (as not-unique username).  Yeh - sorry bout being short, you actually did provide some info and if wasnt for post lag I would have seen your comment above and not replied, or at least edited/deleted my comment when i checked my feed - but by then question was removed. Future note, maybe edit OP rather than comments, as your supposed to (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and it also has visible 'question updated' notice to anyone viewing, so less chance of post lag

Comment: @TinyGiant: _"immutable belief that all users are capable of doing better."_ You can stay stubborn and believe that, or accept that some users will _never_ improve, saving you a lot of effort.

Comment: Hey, the belief that any user is **capable** of improving is not at all tied to the belief that they **will** improve. Those are too absolutely different things. Users do better all the time, and other users don't. If you cannot believe that any user is **capable** of doing better, then you are doing a disservice to the community. @Cerbrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a "mod", but here you go,

[image]